# C# lock inside event handler

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

I have code that looks like the following:

```
private static readonly object MyLock = new object();
private List<int> _myList = new List<int>();

abc.event += (a,b) => Foo();

void SomeFxn()
{
    Foo();
}

private void Foo()
{
    Lock(MyLock)
    {
        _myList.Add(1);
        doSomething();
        _myList.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

When it runs, and Foo gets called from both the event handler and the function, it adds to the list twice before removing.  The lock is not being honored as I am expecting.  How can I ensure that calls to Foo are executed atomically?

Comment: "*The lock is not being honored as I am expecting*" -- what makes you think that? Perhaps you have another place which access `_myList`, but doesn't take the lock before doing so?

Comment: Is `Lock` a typo?

Comment: The lock doesn't stop an event from occurring inside the lock.  It only stop two processes from entering the lock.

Comment: @jdweng /s/processes/threads

Answer (score 3):

We can pretty much guarantee that `lock` is not, in fact, broken. If you're seeing unexpected outcomes, the most likely culprit is that `doSomething` is doing something that is calling into `Foo` via some path, causing you to unexpectedly be *re-entrantly* inside `Foo` twice, **from the same thread**. `lock` *only* protects you from other threads; it is re-entrant by design, meaning: the thread that holds the lock can re-take the lock as many times as it needs (it is really a counter "how many times does the active thread have it", not a boolean "is it taken").

---

As a side note - it looks like your `_myList` is being added at the end and removed at the start; perhaps a `Queue<T>` would be a better option there (`RemoveAt(0)` needs to copy the entire list contents, where-as a queue uses a circular buffer, and does *not* need to copy anything for this scenario). For example:

```cs
private readonly Queue<int> _myQueue = new Queue<int>();
void Foo()
{
    lock (MyLock)
    {
        _myQueue.Enqueue(1);
        doSomething();
        _myQueue.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

---

Additional side note: it feels very odd that an *instance* variable (`_myQueue`) is protected by a `static` lock object; you might want to check that this global lock was intended; you might be able to use `lock (_myQueue)` instead, for per-instance locking.